# I am trying to create features that determine time between events based off of conditional variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to arrange my data set and create a new column in my data set that determines the sequential time between events based off of 2 separate columns.

I have the following code that should help get me there but am having difficulty troubleshooting. Has anyone run into this issue before or can identify the issue with my code?

What I'm trying to use can be found below:

Sample data set can be found below:

```
UNITNUMBER <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
ORDERID <- c(5555,5558,5565,5278,5283,3287,3004,4678,2345,2189,1784,5743,4623,4541)
BREAKDOWN <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
RO_OPENED <- as.Date(c('2016-11-18','2016-11-28','2016-9-15','2017-4-2','2016-12-22','2017-3-8','2016-4-25','2016-2-3','2017-6-7','2016-7-5','2016-4-9','2017-10-27','2017-4-20','2017-5-10'))

test = data.frame(UNITNUMBER,ORDERID,BREAKDOWN,RO_OPENED)

test <-  test %>% data.table(key = c("UNITNUMBER","RO_OPENED"))


test <-  test[, c("UNITNUMBER", "RO_OPENED",
                             "TDIFF", "UNIQUEGROUP") :=
                           list(UNITNUMBER, RO_OPENED,
                                seq(.N), .GRP),
                         by = list(ORDERID)][, numSeq := seq(min(RO_OPENED), max(RO_OPENED)),
                                             by = list(UNIQUEGROUP)][, runningTotal := ifelse(RO_OPENED == numSeq,
                                                                                        seq(.N), 1L), 
                                                               by = list(UNITNUMBER, UNIQUEGROUP)]
```

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Error in seq.Date(min(RO_OPENED), max(RO_OPENED)) : 
  exactly two of 'to', 'by' and 'length.out' / 'along.with' must be specified
```

I'm hoping the result will be 2 new columns giving me a UNIQUEGROUP identifier and the time difference between BREAKDOWNS for each UNITNUMBER and ORDERID like as follows:

```
UNIT OrderID BD    Date      TDIFF
1    5565    0    9/15/2016    NA
1    5555    0    11/18/2016   NA
1    5558    1    11/28/2016   0
1    5278    1    4/2/2017     125
2    5283    1    12/22/2016   0
2    3287    1    3/8/2017     76
3    4678    0    2/3/2016     NA
3    3004    1    4/25/2016    0
3    2345    0    6/7/2017     NA
4    1784    0    4/9/2016     NA
4    2189    0    7/5/2016     NA
4    4623    1    4/20/2017    0
4    4541    0    5/10/2017    NA
4    5743    1    10/27/2017   190
```

Comment: do you insist at using data.table? Since you also tagged dplyr I assume otherwise?

Comment: Regarding your error: check where the error message comes from `Errror in...` and see which arguments you provided and which is missing to clearly define a sequence

Comment: @wusel, thanks for the response. No, I would actually prefer dplyr, but am having issue with subtracting the time of one event by the most recent event for the same UNITNUMBER and made progress using data.table.

Comment: please provide your example data as `dput()`or `data.frame()`. Right now, e.g. dates are not properly stored

Comment: @wusel, thanks for the heads up. Just edited. It should work now.

Comment: I dont really understand your desired output. Why is there a 0 at line 3? Could you explain your logic more precisely? Since ORDERID looks rather unique it is unclear to me which times you want to compare

Comment: @wusel, so UNITNUMBER can be thought of as a Patient and ORDERID can be thought of the identifier for an event (i.e. doctor's appointment). Breakdown is a binary for whether it is an event of interest or routine.

Line 3 is 0 because it is the first occurrence of the event of interest for the UNITNUMBER. Let me know if anything remains unclear. Thanks for taking an interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your job

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  arrange(UNITNUMBER, RO_OPENED) %>% 
  group_by(UNITNUMBER, BREAKDOWN) %>% 
  mutate(TDIFF = coalesce(RO_OPENED - lag(RO_OPENED), 0),
         TDIFF = ifelse(BREAKDOWN == 0, NA, TDIFF))
```

Comment: Major props, @wusel... this solved it. I knew going the dplyr route would've been easier (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)
setorder(test, UNITNUMBER, RO_OPENED)

test[BREAKDOWN == 1,
     TDIFF := c(0, diff(RO_OPENED)),
     by = UNITNUMBER]

test
```